# Bootstrap's accordeon shows all items opened initially in React app, should be closed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, accordion

Here is the React (JSX) code of the accordion:

```
  <div className="panel panel-default receipe">
    <div className="panel-heading">
      <h4 className="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#recipes" href={"#collapse"+i}>
          {recipe.name}
        </a>          
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id={"collapse"+(i++)} class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <Ingredients ingredients={recipe.ingredients}/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/lafisrap/pen/LWdovO

It shows the titles and items correctly, and items can be opened and closed. It's just that they are open at the beginning. I don't want to use  `$("#receipes").collapse("hide");` as it is not nice ;-) to put jQuery code into React. (other opinions?)

Comment: This kind of behaviour [is problematic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27846480/6499571) when you combine Bootstrap with React.js. I don't know if using [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels) is an option for you, but it's usually the best choice. It supports panels and you can collapse them using React's state.

Comment: I'll try this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using `class` instead of `className` on this line:

`<div id={"collapse"+(i++)} class="panel-collapse collapse">`

Check line #48 in your codepen.

And by the way, I think this line `id={"collapse"+(i++)}` can be also written like:

```
id={`collapse${i++}`}
```

Looks better